# How should HTML and data look to use DataTable responsive display type 'column'?

Tags: jquery, datatables

I'm trying to use jQuery datatables responsive to display a column on the left of my data to show hidden columns.

This result is shown in this example from their api / reference docs:

https://datatables.net/extensions/responsive/examples/child-rows/column-control.html

It says I should set:

```
responsive: {
    details: {
        type: 'column'
    }
}
```

Which I have done, but when I do this, I get the following error:

`Requested unknown parameter '0' for row 0`

Which asks me to look at this: https://www.datatables.net/manual/tech-notes/4

I can't see quite why this error is occurring, going through the tech notes.

My datatables config option (abridged) looks like this (note the first column set as the `control` column).

```
var table = $('#list').DataTable({
            responsive: {
                details: {
                    type: 'column',
                    target: 0
                }
            },
            columns: [
                {                        
                    className: 'control',
                    orderable: false
                },
                {
                    data: 'Id',
                    className: 'never'
                },
                {
                    data: 'EventDate',
                    className: 'desktop'
                }
    ]});
```

My HTML (abridged) is set like this (note the first `th` to contain the control column).

```
<table class="table dt-responsive no-wrap dataTable table-striped table-bordered table-hover" id="bet-list">
    <thead>
    <tr>
        <th></th>
        <th>Id</th>
        <th>Event Date</th>
        <th>Event</th>
    </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody></tbody>
</table>
```

If I don't set the type and let the control occur inline in the first data column things work ok. What's also annoying is that even after the error, the control displays in its own column and behaves as I'd expect, so I'm not quite sure what the error is going on about.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to solve this by performing the following:

1. Make sure the HTML had a blank  to contain the control column.
2. Make sure I always had a column set to `visible: false`.
3. Add a `columnDef` option to the datatable, mine looked like this:

   ```
           columnDefs: [
               {
                   targets: 0,
                   orderable: false,
                   className: 'all control'
               }
           ]
   ```
4. Set the column you want to be the control to refer to some server side column, in my case I added a field to my server side function called 'Control' which just returned an empty string. I then added this to the front of my `columns` array like this:

   ```
           columns: [
               {
                   data: 'Control'
               },
   ```
5. I set the config on the datatables responsive to target the first column like this.

   `responsive: {
     details: {
       type: 'column',
       target: 0
     }
   }`

I found the relationship between columns, columnDefs and the responsive config confusing due to the 'targets' property which is not very well explained in the docs.

Here's how I now understand it.

The `responsive.details.target` value tells responsive which column index triggers the responsive behaviour, so in the case of a column layout it should be set to the column you want to have a click event on.

The HTML needs to have a `<th>` in there for the control column and this need to pair with a columns array record. The columns array record need to have some data to bind to.

Your server side data, needs to have something that column array can attach to, else I just ended up getting all my data shifted one column to the left. In my case I just output a field with an empty string.

The `columnDef` seemed to be needed, even if I set the same properties on my column regarding classNames. The `targets` option in columnDefs tells datatables which column to apply the settings to. So in my example it sets the orderable and className properties.

Answer (score 0):

You don't have to return an empty string (point 4 from @dougajmcdonald).

This is sufficient:

```
columns: [
   ...
   ...
   {data: null, defaultContent: '', orderable: false, searchable: false}
]
```